# Messed up option in select tag when value contains more than one word

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I'm building a drop-down menu this way:

```
var htmlString = '<select id="sAddress">';

for (var i=0; i<branchesArray.length; i++){     
    htmlString += '<option value=' + branchesArray[i].branchName + '>' + branchesArray[i].branchName + '</option>';
}
htmlString += '</select>';
$('.shopAddress').append(htmlString);
```

Now, the problem is that if `branchesArray[i].branchName` contains one word than it's OK, but if it contains two words separated by space, than instead of getting this:

```
<option value="West Coast">West Coast</option>
```

I'm getting this:

```
<option Coast="" value="West">West Coast</option>
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use quotes when the value of an attribute contains whitespaces. If there's possibility that your string contains a double quote, you have to replace it (see second example):

```
htmlString += '<option value="' + branchesArray[i].branchName + '">' + branchesArray[i].branchName + '</option>'
```

Replacing double quotes by HTML entity `&quot;`:

```
htmlString += '<option value="' + branchesArray[i].branchName.replace(/"/g, '&quot;') + '">' + branchesArray[i].branchName + '</option>'
```

Currently, your generated HTML looks like:

```
<option value=West Coast>West Coast</option>  which is interpreted as:
<option value="West" Coast>West Coast</option> (attributes: value=west, Coast="")
<option value="West" Coast="">West Coast</option>
```

Comment: First option worked like a charm but good to know about the second one as well. Thanks!

Comment: Add a double quote `"` to your branchName. You'll see that the first method is not sufficient for this.

Comment: @Ash Try: `branchesArray[0].branchName = 'Unexpected example" style="color:red'`.